# Ajax data two-way data binding strategies?

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-binding

I'd like to 
1) Draw create form fields and populate them with data from javascript objects
2) Update those backing objects whenever the value of the form field changes

Number 1 is easy. I have a few js template systems I've been using that work quite nicely.

Number 2 may require a bit of thought. A quick google search on "ajax data binding" turned up a few systems which seem basically one-way. They're designed to update a UI based on backing js objects, but don't seem to address the question of how to update those backing objects when changes are made to the UI. Can anyone recommend any libraries which will do this for me? It's something I can write myself without too much trouble, but if this question has already been thought through, I'd rather not duplicate the work.

////////////////////// edit /////////////////

I've created my own jquery plugin to accomplish this. Here it is. Please let me know if it's useful and if you think it might be worth making it more "official". Also let me know if you have problems or questions.

```
/*

    Takes a jquery object and binds its form elements with a backing javascript object. Takes two arguments: the object 
    to be bound to, and an optional "changeListener", which must implement a "changeHappened" method.

    Example: 

    // ============================
    // =     backing object       =
    // ============================

    demoBean = {
        prop1 : "val",
        prop2 : [
            {nestedObjProp:"val"},
            {nestedObjProp:"val"}
        ],
        prop3 : [
            "stringVal1",
            "stringVal12"
        ]
    }

    // ===========================
    // =        FORM FIELD       =
    // ===========================

    <input class="bindable" name="prop2[1].nestedObjProp">


    // ===========================
    // =       INVOCATION        =
    // ===========================

    $jq(".bindable").bindData( 
        demoBean, 
        {changeHappened: function(){console.log("change")}}
    )


*/


(function($){


    // returns the value of the property found at the given path
    // plus a function you can use to set that property
    var navigateObject = function(parentObj, pathArg){
        var immediateParent = parentObj;
        var path = pathArg
            .replace("[", ".")
            .replace("]", "")
            .replace("].", ".")
            .split(".");
        for(var i=0; i< (path.length-1); i++){
            var currentPathKey = path[i];
            immediateParent = immediateParent[currentPathKey];
            if(immediateParent === null){
                throw new Error("bindData plugin encountered a null value at  " + path[i] + " in path" + path);
            }
        }

        return {
            value: immediateParent[path[path.length - 1]],
            set: function(val){
                immediateParent[path[path.length - 1]] = val
            },
            deleteObj: function(){
                if($.isArray(immediateParent)){
                    immediateParent.splice(path[path.length - 1], 1);
                }else{
                    delete  immediateParent[path[path.length - 1]];
                }
            } 
        }

    }

    var isEmpty = function(str){
        return str == null || str == "";
    }

    var bindData = function(parentObj, changeListener){

        var parentObj,
            radioButtons = [];
        var changeListener;
        var settings;
        var defaultSettings = {
            // if this flag is true, you can put a label in a field,
            // like <input value="Phone Number"/>, and the value
            // won't be replaced by a blank value in the parentObj
            // Additionally, if the user clicks on the field, the field will be cleared.
            allowLabelsInfields: true 
        };

        // allow two forms: 
        // function(parentObj, changeListener)
        // and function(settings). 
        if(arguments.length == 2){
            parentObj = arguments[0];
            changeListener = arguments[1]
            settings = defaultSettings;
        }else{  
            settings = $jq.extend(defaultSettings, arguments[0]);
            parentObj = settings.parentObj;
            changeListener = settings.changeListener;
        }

        var changeHappened = function(){};
        if(typeof changeListener != "undefined"){
            if(typeof changeListener.changeHappened == "function"){
                changeHappened = changeListener.changeHappened;
            }else{
                throw new Error("A changeListener must have a method called 'changeHappened'.");
            }
        };
        this.each(function(key,val){
            var formElem = $(val);
            var tagName = formElem.attr("tagName").toLowerCase();
            var fieldType;
          if(tagName == "input"){
            fieldType = formElem.attr("type").toLowerCase();
          }else{
            fieldType = tagName;
          }


            // Use the "name" attribute as the address of the property we want to bind to.
            // Except if it's a radio button, in which case, use the "value" because "name" is the name of the group
            // This should work for arbitrarily deeply nested data. 
            var navigationResult = navigateObject(parentObj, formElem.attr(fieldType === "radio"? "value" : "name"));

            // populate the field with the data in the backing object

            switch(fieldType){

        // is it a radio button? If so, check it or not based on the 
        // boolean value of navigationResult.value
        case "radio":
          radioButtons.push(formElem);
          formElem.data("bindDataPlugin", {navigationResult: navigationResult});
          formElem.attr("checked", navigationResult.value);
          formElem.change(function(){
            // Radio buttons only seem to update when _selected_, not 
            // when deselected. So if one is clicked, update the bound
            // object for all of them. I know it's a little ugly,
            // but it works.
            $jq.each(radioButtons, function(index, button){
              var butt = $jq(button);
              butt.data("bindDataPlugin").navigationResult.set(butt.attr("checked"));
            });
            navigationResult.set(formElem.attr("checked"));           
            changeHappened();
          });
          break;

        case "text":
          // if useFieldLabel is true, it means that the field is 
          // self-labeling. For example, an email field whose 
          // default value is "Enter Email".
          var useFieldLabel = isEmpty( navigationResult.value )
                   && !isEmpty( formElem.val() )  
                   && settings.allowLabelsInfields;
          if(useFieldLabel){
           var labelText = formElem.val();
           formElem.click(function(){
             if(formElem.val() === labelText){
               formElem.val("");
             }
           })
          }else{
           formElem.attr("value", navigationResult.value);
          }
          formElem.keyup(function(){
           navigationResult.set(formElem.attr("value"));
           changeHappened();
          });

          break;

        case "select":
          var domElem = formElem.get(0);
                $jq.each(domElem.options, function(index, option){
                    if(option.value === navigationResult.value){
                        domElem.selectedIndex = index;
                    }
                });
                formElem.change(function(){
                    navigationResult.set(formElem.val());
                })
          break;

        case "textarea":
          formElem.text(navigationResult.value);
          formElem.keyup(function(){
           changeHappened();
           navigationResult.set(formElem.val());
          });
          break;
      }


        });
        return this;
    };

    bindData.navigateObject = navigateObject;

    $.fn.bindData = bindData;

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you convert your "jQuery plugin" edit into an answer so I can vote for it?

Comment: @morgancodes: I've created a [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nKqMN/) from your code and replaced console.log by something browser-independent. Could you have a look please? I didn't get the idea what your code should do.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of libraries out there to achieve what you want.

For starters, you can use [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) to get the Ajax functionality. The method that gets triggered for the form field's `onChange` event should make a DWR call to the corresponding backing object

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mihir,
I was thinking of something a little more lightweight, probably front-end-only, or server agnostic. But I'll take a look at DWR.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a proposal for an enhancement to jQuery core that implements decently reach data binding including a two binding (source to target, and target to source).

They call it **Data Linking** - which is odd since the name of this concept in all other MS technologies (WinForms, WPF, WebForms, etc...) is **DataBinding**.

[Link to the MS Proposal](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/proposal-for-adding-data-linking-to-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

[DataBind](http://www.opencomponents.net/databind/) - a template plugin for jQuery. The library has a method `unbinddata()`, which collects the data back to json-array.

Unfortunately, the library works only with form inputs.

If you made some solution, can I see it?

Comment: Sounds like it might be pretty similar to what I've created. Pasted it above.